# Sound_play action library

Tags: ros, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a reason the sound_play library is not implemented as actions? It seems odd to have a system with no feedback as to whether the sound actually played/was found, and the API seems very un-ROS-y.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11281/sound_play-action-library/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-09-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the main problem is with festival, as AFAIK it does not provide any feedback once you issue a command. Therefore you will never know if the text to speech has finished saying what it has to say.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2011-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-01-04**:
I suggest that you file an enhancement ticket, and a patch will make it happen much sooner.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2011-09-22**:
A valid point, but if you issue a say command without sound_play running, then the current library will print out an error, but give no actual feedback to the program that called the command.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-09-10**:
Ticketed as https://kforge.ros.org/audiocommon/trac/ticket/11